# How to check the schema of database

Tags: sql, c, linux, gcc, sqlite

Iam using sqlite3 and want to know that how can we know if we have to check the schema of database and also what would be the most appropriate approach to update it according to new schema ..i mean to say if there is change in schema then  what approach i should use "drop and the  then create tables " or "alter the tables only ...."..

I want to clarify this thing that through schema i specifically mean to say if there are new columns added in the table then how can we know.What would be the correct approach.

Platform : Linux , gcc compiler

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) is a great tool for maintaining your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

From an sqlite3 command prompt you can use 
.schema ?TABLE?